# collectionViewCell subview is shown despite a .isHidden = true, when CV contentInset is updated (with video)

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, thread-safety

I'm making a chat app like iMessage. I use a `UICollectionView` with a vertical `FlowLayout` Each cell is a stack view containing (1) a "header" view (that contains a date UILabel, like in iMessage) , and (2), under it, the bubble UILabel in which I put the message text.

Here is the code I use to dequeue cell :

```
let pos = indexPath.row
let message:Message = messagesData[pos]

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MessageCollectionViewCell

cell.setMessage(message)
cell.headerView.isHidden = pos == 0 || message.dateDMY != messages[pos - 1].dateDMY

return cell
```

Like in iMessage, I display it if the date of the previous message is not the same or if it's the first message (user scrolled to top).

I use an `.interactive` keyboard, with a bottom bar as an `inputAccessoryView`. In order to always have the last message right above the bottom bar, I implemented this listener for notification `UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` :

```
@objc func onKeyboardChangeFrame(notif:Notification)
{
    
    let userInfo = notif.userInfo!
    let beginFrameValue = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! CGRect
    let endFrameValue = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! CGRect
    
    if(!beginFrameValue.equalTo(endFrameValue))
    {   
        let oldContentInset = collectionView.contentInset.bottom
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration:0.05)
        {
            // endFrameValue.height contains the height of the keyboard + inputAccessoryView height, so it's the perfect value for the contentInset
            self.collectionView.contentInset.bottom = endFrameValue.height
            self.collectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = endFrameValue.height
        }
       
        // no need to scroll when inset is reduced : the cells automatically go down. But when the inset is increased, additional scroll is needed
        if(endFrameValue.height > oldContentInset)
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.scrollToBottomCell()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When the user sends like 15 messages (so all the messages cells inserted doesn't fit into the screen), then after that, quickly close the keyboard, the CV contentInset is adjusted to decrease (to display the last message close to the bottom bar). Due to that contentInset decrease, new cells are inserted to the top of the CV because there is space available.

*Some* of these news cells inserted in the top automatically have their headerView shown, despite cellForItem function explicitly told to `isHidden = true`. With the debugger, I could see that these header ***do have their isHidden set to true***, but they are shown anyway. Moreover, these header ***are not detected in the layout inspector.***.

Anyone has an idea of what's wrong ?

Comment: hard to tell what's the problem. but I suggest 2 things :
1. forget for the layout inspector. use print/nslog and console and just log the states of headerview frame and hidden.
2. try to split the tests. for example, show/hide only the header part. disable all other UI views

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! According to your experience, layout inspector is not very reliable ? (i'm quite new to iOS dev). I already tried plenty of tests, what I can only see is that a view with a isHidden prop set to true is shown on the device. I guess this only state should never happen, if I had to debug it, i'd need to debug UIKit.. Tried setNeedsDisplay but it has no effect.

Comment: The most frustrating thing with this problem is not the problem itself ( i can find ugly workaround to hide the header when not expected, just like to recall setHeader in a DispatchQueue.main.async block), but it's the fact that, now, I don't feel anymore safe doing any UI update within a cellForItem collectionView function, and my app is plenty of them. Would be better to understand what's really going on behind the scene when doing isHidden = true

Comment: Lackar
we can discuss this on chat if you want
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226451/me-and-jerem

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your answer, I was desperate to find the solution. It's the first time I use the chat, how can I send you a message there ?

Comment: just write in the textbox and press "send" (desktop web version)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226454/discussion-between-user1105951-and-jerem-lachkar).